# NEO4j cypher query to match same words

Tags: java, python, neo4j

I have two words BANGALURU and BENGALURU.

Now I have to create nodes in neo4j such that I have to create only one node that means BANGALURU and BENGALURU should be considered as one and create only one node

please tell me how can I create neo4j cypher query for this.

Comment: Can you better describe your use case in broader scope? It sounds like you need quick lookup of nodes via words. What labels are you using in your graph? Are there other cases where you need to support multiple words matching to a single node?

Comment: MY problem statement is like this.                                                                           I need to create nodes in neo4j as follows                                                              MERGE (l:Location {Type:'Place', name:"BANGALORE"})   here the query is created with the label Location and with the property BANGALORE. Now I have one more property name called "BENGALORE" . now If I am trying to create a node , it should tell me already the node BENGALORE is created that means it should consider BANGALORE and BENGALORE as same. like for Bombay and mumbai etc...

Answer (score 0):

There's no good way to have a node with two values for the same property that will support fast lookup with an index.

I'd recommend creating a :Location node with that name that has an :ALIAS relationship to the other node. Maybe also add an :Alias label to the node. Something like:

```
(:Location:Alias{Type:'Place', name:'BENGALORE'})<-[:ALIAS]-(:Location{Type:'Place', name:'BANGALORE'})
```

You can use the :Location node without the :Alias as the root node of any further connections.

Matching will get slightly more complicated, however. A lookup query might look like:

```
MATCH (a:Location)<-[:ALIAS*0..1]-(l:Location)
WHERE a.name = {nameLookup} AND NOT l:Alias
```

This will work for both aliased and non-aliased nodes, as the minimum bounds for the relationship pattern of 0 will match the :Location node to itself (`a` and `l` will be the same node).